# Change border-spacing for column with different span

Tags: html, css

I have a question how to achieve a view like below, using only native html table elements.

[image]

Basically what I would like to do is to change the border-spacing of those tds that fall under the th with span equal to 4. Is that even possible?

```css
table {
  background-color: gray;
  border-spacing: 0.5em;

}

td, th {
 background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Th1</th>
          <th colspan="4">Th2</th>
          <th>Th3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Td</td>
          <td>Td for th span 4</td>
          <td>Td for th span 4</td>
          <td>Td for th span 4</td>
          <td>Td for th span 4</td>
          <td>Td</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Don't think it's possible - border spacing is set at table level

Comment: @Pete - any clue how to achieve such design in another way but without adding too much markup to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try inserting table inside table

```css
.table1 {
  background-color: gray;
  border-spacing: 0.5em;
}

td,
th {
  background-color: orange;
}

.table2 {
  background-color: gray;
  border-spacing: 0.1em 0;
}

.holder {
  background-color: grey;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<table class='table1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Th1</th>
      <th colspan="4">Th2</th>
      <th>Th3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Td</td>
      <td colspan='4' class='holder'>
        <table class='table2'>
          <tr>
            <td>Td for th span 4</td>
            <td>Td for th span 4</td>
            <td>Td for th span 4</td>
            <td>Td for th span 4</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>Td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate this with padding and apply coloration to only the content:

```css
table {
  background-color: gray;
  border-spacing: 0.3em 0.2em;
}

td,
th {
  background: orange content-box;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

td:nth-last-child(2) {
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Th1</th>
      <th colspan="4">Th2</th>
      <th>Th3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Td</td>
      <td>Td for th span 4</td>
      <td>Td for th span 4</td>
      <td>Td for th span 4</td>
      <td>Td for th span 4</td>
      <td>Td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```